# Tenho definição de classe mas o objeto vindo do JSON não mantém os métodos

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho um problema no momento que recebo o JSON do servidor e quero usar ele como se fosse minha classe local.

```
//classes

export class Pessoa {
 id: number;
 nome: string;
 raca: Raca;

 constructor(){}

 getTeste1(): string {
   return this.id + ' - ' + this.nome;
 }

}

export class Raca {
 id: number;
 nome: string;

 constructor(){}

 getTeste2(): string {
   return this.id + ' - ' + this.nome;
 }
}
```

```js
//JSON recebido
{
   "id": 20354,
   "nome": "CRISOSTOMO KOLLING",
   "raca":    {
      "nome": "BRANCA",
      "id": 2
   }
}
```

```js
//recebimento do servidor
let pessoa: Pessoa;

buscar(nome: string){
 this.rest.get(nome).subscribe((v: Pessoa) => {Object.assign(this.pessoa, v)})
}
```

Eu esperava poder usar this.pessoa.raca.getTeste2() assim como uso no java.
Mas não consigo.
O this.pessoa é do tipo PESSOA, mas o this.pessoa.raca NÃO é do tipo RACA, mas sim Object.

Como faço para que o retorno do JSON preencha a tipagem que eu determinei com as classes?
Ou eu não posso criar métodos dentro dos arquivos onde crio a tipagem da classe?

Comment: Tenta fazer com o new e passando o parametros para o construtor. tipo this.pessoa= new Pessoa(v)

Answer (score 0):

Tente desta forma:

```
export class Pessoa {
  id: number;
  nome: string;
  raca: Raca;

  constructor(data?){
    this.id = data.id ? data.id : null;
    this.nome = data.nome ? data.nome : null;
    this.raca = data.raca ? new Raca(data.raca) : null;
  }

  getTeste1(): string {
    return this.id + ' - ' + this.nome;
  }

}

export class Raca {
  id: number;
  nome: string;

  constructor(data?){
    this.id = data.id ? data.id : null;
    this.nome = data.nome ? data.nome : null;
  }

  getTeste2(): string {
    return this.id + ' - ' + this.nome;
  }
}

buscar(nome: string){
  this.rest.get(nome).subscribe( result => {
    if(result){
      this.pessoa = new Pessoa(result)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Funcionou !! Apenas tive que adaptar. No construtor eu tive que colocar um ```If ``` antes das atribuições dentro do construtor, pois o angular não acha os atributos. E tive que inicializar os atributos com null em sua própria definição: ```export class Pessoa {
  id: number = null;
  nome: string = null;
  raca: Raca = null;

  constructor(data?){
      if (data){
        this.id = data.id ? data.id : null;
        this.nome = data.nome ? data.nome : null;
        this.raca = data.raca ? new Raca(data.raca) : null;
      }
  }
...```